# Where does django look for sqlite3 installation/libraries?

Tags: django, sqlite

Am having a bit of a problem making my django application run in SUSE linux 9. I have Python2.5 installed well, Django 1.0 installed well. Am able to execute django command
django-admin startproject  fine

But when i run the runserver command i get the error below. i have a folder with sqlite3, i can go in there and actually run the sqlite3* application, now am wondering where does Django look for the sqlite libraries? and how can i fix this?

```
Validating models...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function inner_run at 0x2a96cb4f50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 48, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 122, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 22, in get_validation_errors
    from django.db import models, connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    backend = __import__('%s%s.base' % (_import_path, settings.DATABASE_ENGINE), {}, {}, [''])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured, "Error loading %s module: %s" % (module, exc)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading sqlite3 module: No module named _sqlite3
```

Gath

Comment: How did you install the sqlite libraries?  Are you using virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the `sqlite3` application, but not the Python libraries. Since they usually come as part of the Python distribution for versions 2.5 upwards, the likelihood is that you have a minimal Python install.

I don't know anything about how SUSE deals with packages, but try installing the Python-dev package or equivalent.

(Also note that SUSE 9 seems like a very old version - it's currently up to 11. You might want to upgrade your whole system.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you didn't have the `sqlite3-devel` package installed when you built Python. Install that package, rebuild Python, then try again.